# CUPS printing to canon MG5660 not actually printing

Tags: debian, printing, cups, raspbian

I have an up to date raspberry Pi running the default flavour of Raspbian connected over wifi, and a Canon MG5660 connected over wifi.

I have installed CUPS on the Pi. 
The web interface for CUPS detected the network printer and went all the way through the wizard, (picking the Canon MG5600 series printer driver assuming it would cover the 5660) all successful, no errors.

But when I print anything, no job seems to make it to the printer. The job que of CUPS says the jobs have been completed, and gives a completetion time, but nothing ever prints out, and the printer gives no indication anything at all.

I have tested the printer with my Windows machine just fine.

One time when I restarted CUPS and I got the following in /var/log/cups/error_log:

```
W [10/Jan/2016:14:33:01 +1100] failed to CreateProfile: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'Canon_MG5600_series-Gray..' already exists
W [10/Jan/2016:14:33:01 +1100] failed to CreateProfile: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'Canon_MG5600_series-RGB..' already exists
W [10/Jan/2016:14:33:01 +1100] failed to CreateDevice: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:device id 'cups-Canon_MG5600_series' already exists
E [10/Jan/2016:14:33:01 +1100] Unable to open listen socket for address [v1.::]:631 - Address family not supported by protocol.
E [10/Jan/2016:14:34:05 +1100] [cups-deviced] PID 2866 (snmp) stopped with status 1!
E [10/Jan/2016:14:41:30 +1100] Unable to open listen socket for address [v1.::]:631 - Address family not supported by protocol.
```

I don't think the ColorManger errors are really important, and that the Port 631 is realted to the CUPS webgui.

I have tried pausing and resuming the printer to no affect (including a restart of CUPSD after resuming).

It is getting harder and harder to diagnose a problem that gives no actual indication.